# sending strings to another application

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, sendmessage

Does anyone have any idea how i could modify the example from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14519/Using-Windows-APIs-from-C-again

in order to send strings of data to a textbox?Using Spy++ i was able to determine the app caption, and the buttons, and edits captions of the targeted app, And i have succesfully pressed a button, but i would also like to be able to put some text in a textbox.Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you're using C# you may as well use the System.Windows.Automation namespace. Use the ValuePattern.SetValue to change the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the HWND of the TextBox to which you want to send the text, this code should do it:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lParam);

    private const int WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C;

    ...

    public void SetTextOnRemoteTextBox(string text)
    {
        SendMessage(textBox1.Handle, WM_SETTEXT, (IntPtr)text.Length, text);
    }
```

Cheers